# Dual monitor connection issues - Thinkpad

Tags: display, hdmi, thinkpad

I have an issue with dual monitors. Graphics is Intel 520.

- I can connect 2 monitors to my docking station when i use either 1x HDMI or DP and 1x VGA.
- I can not connect 2 monitors using 1x HDMI and 1x DP or DVI.

When i have both monitors connected using HDMI and DP only 1 monitor is detected.

- If i remove the HDMI cable the second monitor which was not detected becomes connected and works, but not when both are plugged in.
- I can fix this by connected the second monitor to VGA, then both work.

I would prefer to use 1x HDMI and 1x DVI or DP.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: What model is the ThinkPad? What model is the docking station?

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for your reply. I have the T460s and the docking station that came with it. The docking station has 1x VGA, 1x DVI, 1x DP. Thanks for your help

Comment: First, read through the [manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t460s_ug_en.pdf) pages 32 - 34 and make sure you have tried everything they suggest.

Comment: I am not readily finding any limitations that would hinder you. With that said, I can't research the exact docking station without its manufacturer and model. This info should be somewhere on the docking station.

Comment: Hi Brian, the docking station is a Thinkpad Pro Dock Type 40A1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the DP, DVI, and HDMI at the same time. So, to setup two monitor, you can use either the DP, DVI OR HDMI, and the VGA port. See docking station documentation [here](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/options/tp_pro_dock_sp40a02134.pdf).

Comment: Hi Brian, you are a champion!!! Thank you very much for your effort in helping me out. Disappointing that this will not work for me, i guess ill have to revert back to VGA. perhaps one day i can return the favour. All the best